# Omit repetition in nginx configuration

Tags: nginx

I have a very simple `nginx` so my local services can be nicely accessed from outside.

This is the config

```
user httpdusr everyone;
#####################
worker_processes  1;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    include /opt/etc/nginx/mime.types;

    location / {
      try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ index.html;
      root /share/CE_CACHEDEV1_DATA/Web/fitness/;
    }

    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /share/Web/.htpasswd
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name service1.domain.com;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:9091;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name service2.domain.com;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name service3.domain.com;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1;
    }
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name service4.domain.com;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:32400;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name service5.domain.com;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:5601;
    }

    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /share/Web/.htpasswd;
  }

}
```

I am no NGINX expert, this is what I came up with a couple of tutorials. However, as you can see, the number of services is growing and the repetition is getting bigger and bigger.
Being a developer... it hurts me inside :-)

I know it is possible, but I do not know how to get a common part like:

```
common() {
  listen 80;
  server_name <param1>;

  location / {
    proxy_pass <param2>;
  }
}
```

and then use it like

```
common(service1.domain.com, http://localhost:9091)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should have a look at [OpenResty](https://github.com/openresty/openresty) and especially the [lua-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Nginx [include](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) function, but you can't do parameters. I don't know any way to achieve exactly what you want, other than perhaps some home grown template system. I wouldn't bother.

Long hand Nginx configuration files are fine, and easy to maintain. Once they reach thousands of lines becomes more difficult to manage, but at your scale it's typically no problem.

For organisation, it's good to have one file per domain, with as many server blocks as are required for http / https, subdomains, etc. The main Nginx file includes them. You can include code that is exactly the same between config files, as below.

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
include /etc/nginx/enabled-sites/*;
```

**/etc/nginx/enabled-sites/site1.conf**

```
server {
  location / {
    // etc        
  }

  include /etc/nginx/fragments/security-headers;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/fragments/security-headers**

```
# Security headers
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=2592000; includeSubDomains; preload";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' www.google-analytics.com ajax.googleapis.com www.google.com google.com gstatic.com www.gstatic.com connect.facebook.net facebook.com;";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header Referrer-Policy "origin";
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple options are available to solve what you want here.

One is to use http://nginx.org/r/map directive:

```
map $host $pphost {
    hostnames;

    default http://127.0.0.1:29159;

    service1.example.org http://127.0.0.1:9091;
    service2.example.org http://127.0.0.1:8080;        
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name service1.example.org service2.example.org …;

    location / {
        proxy_pass $pphost;
    }
}
server {
    listen 29159;
    return 200 $http_host\n$request_uri\n200\tOK;
    # this is simply used as the defailt fallback,                                                                                                                                                                            
    # to avoid having proxy_pass within an extra if
}
```

Another is to use http://nginx.org/r/include directive, together with a script that would take care of the various permutatious of your server configurations, written in your favourite language of choice.

Note that although you cannot use http://nginx.org/r/set in any context — it requires `server`, `location` or `if` — you can use `include` in any context.  As for `map`, it can actually only be defined globally within the `http` context (e.g., on the same level as where `server` goes), so, that's a perfect way to configure your preferences.